# Python 2.7.15 adds a new line in Windows to the end but not on Linux. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-2.7, printing, newline

This is **not** a typical "how do I strip a new line or spaces" question...

I am new to python in general. But I am aware of

```
print ("test", end="")
print ("test", end="")
```

for Python 3 and

```
print "test",
print "test",
```

for Python 2

Python 3 implementation will print correctly on both Linux and Windows machines; however the Python 2 implementation will add an extra line at the end of the execution on Windows based machines (but not Linux, there it prints correctly). Is there any way to get rid of this new line?

I have searched around and I cant seem to find anyone talking about this particular issue. Here is a screenshot for demonstration:

[image: New Line issue in Windows Python 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to a few people about this and doing some research. It appears the most straightforward way around this issue is to directly use:

```
sys.stdout.write()
```

instead of print. You can then format your output similar to the way C/C++ and Java work.

Answer (score 1):

So, in accordance with the [print documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print)

> Standard output is defined as the file object named stdout

And we probably assume that python I\O are system dependent, so that's how we could try to guess the explanation of this situation, even thought print documentation states:

> A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement
>   ends with a comma.

**OR** The reason is that Windows & Linux threat `print` statement differently (since `print` is a statement in Python 2, and a [function call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in Python 3).

Back to the question, how to get rid of this line:
I used  [future](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) statement for print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('test', end=' ')
print('test', end='')
```

If I find any reasonable explanation, I will update the answer (should be somewhere !).